# I want to know the difference in meaning between 'to' and 'and'

Tags: grammar

I would like to know the difference between the two sentences in meaning.

1. Let's all take a time and be thankful that we are Koreans.
2. Let's all take a time to be thankful that we are Koreans.

Please, could you tell me the difference?

Comment: It should be: Let's all take THE time to be...

Comment: Or "Let's all take time" without the article,  or "Let's all take a moment..."

Answer (score 3):

There is no practical difference.

They are slightly different in their literal meaning.

- The first uses "and" to join two actions: taking time, and being thankful. It does not *explicitly* say that the time will be used to be thankful. However, this is clearly the intention, and it should be read that way.
- The second lists just one action: taking time. It then *explicitly* says the purpose of that action is a second action (being thankful).

There may be an individual preference for "to" or "and". One of my favourite authors, J. R. R. Tolkien, was annoyed with the editors or typesetters of his novel, *The Lord of the Rings*, for "correcting" some of his phrases, including "try and say" to "try to say".